# Does QuestDB have EXPLAIN

Tags: questdb

Postgres has syntax to show the query plan for a SQL statement:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/using-explain.html

Does QuestDB have something equivalent so that I can see the query plan that would result from my SQL before actually executing it?

Answer (score 1):

QuestDB added the EXPLAIN clause a few weeks ago. There is a [nice blogpost](https://questdb.io/blog/sql-performance-tuning-introducing-explain/) with details for interpreting the results, but if you just want to start using it all you have to do is prefix your queries with the `EXPLAIN` keyword

Answer (score 0):

The QuestDB [docs](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/rest/#overview) show an `explain` option for the `/exec` HTTP endpoint. However, I can't get it to work on my instance running v6.2.

It should work like this:

```sh
curl -G \
    --data-urlencode "query=select * from t limit 2;" \
    --data-urlencode "explain=true" \
    http://localhost:9000/exec
```

Comment: "explain" url parameter is not the same as "EXPLAIN" keyword. It causes backend to return a bit of metadata ('jitCompiled' flag) along with result .